# Convergence in the sense of distribution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $D(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of all smooth functions valued in $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support.

I need to find a sequence of functions $f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall \phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$ the limit
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int f_n(x) \phi(x) dx$ exists but the sequence $\{f_n \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ doesn't converge for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Basically the problem can be state like:

> Find a sequence of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that converges in $D'(\mathbb{R})$ in the sense of distributions, but does't converge in any point of $\mathbb{R}$.

For the moment I think that
$f_n (x) = (\cos(nx))^{(n)},$ where ${}^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$:th derivate of the function, is not convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ and
$$\int f_n \phi \, dx = (-1)^{n} \int \cos(nx) \phi^{(n)}\, dx \label{1}\tag{1}$$
by integrating by parts $n$ times.

Now, remembering the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma:

> Let $f$ be a $C^1$ function with compact support. Then $\int f(x) e^{inx} dx$ is $O(|n|^{-1})$.

It is to say, that if I can prove that I can pass the limit over the integral and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \phi^{(n)}$ is a $C^1$ function with compact support then, the expression in (\ref{1}) tends to $0$.

But I can't see that this is true or false.

Any help or another example is welcome.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

The limit $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \phi^{(n)}(x)$ need not exist for any smooth function with compact support. For example, let $\chi$ be a compactly supported function equal to $1$ on $[0,1]$. Then, if $\phi(x) = \chi(x) \cos(x)$, you have :
$$\forall x\in[0,1], \phi^{(2n)}(x) = (-1)^n\cos(x)$$
which does not converge to anything.